# SQL query to select "greater than" in hybrid number & text field

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

Please assume the table design won't change. I know it isn't perfect. Imagine a single-column database table with these rows:

```
0.8 ounces
1.8 ounces
1 ounce
2 ounces
15 ounces
15.6 ounces
1 pound
9.9 pounds
15 pounds
100.1 pounds
```

Notice how there are decimals and plurals.

I need help constructing a SELECT query which does NOT include any row more than 10 pounds.

In other words, the SELECT query ignores the last 2 rows in the above database table.

Comment: The table design simply isn't appropriate for the task. The table contains strings, and they are just that: strings. If you want values and units instead, then you should store them as such: a value column plus a unit column. And tadaaa the problem's gone!

Comment: Whats the column constraint?

Comment: More than 10? So, 10 and 10.0 are accepted, right?

Comment: Please assume the table design won't change.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments section: Change your table design and make this two columns. You should even have a unit table and conversion factors.

However, if you really need to keep this table and still have to compare with ten pounds, you *could* tackle this with string functions and some conditions for the conversion as follows. Again: I don't recommend this. Change your table instead!

You get the value in the string with `SUBSTRING_INDEX`:

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(col, ' ', 1)
```

You can cast the value string to numeric then:

```
CAST( SUBSTRING_INDEX(col, ' ', 1) AS DECIMAL(10,2) )
```

(I must admit, though, that I don't know whether this works with a locale setting using the comma for a decimal separator. Probably you'd have to replace the point with the decimal separator first, but then I don't know how to determine which symbol is set as the decimal separator in MySQL.)

You get the unit with `SUBSTRING_INDEX` and a negative count parameter:

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(col, ' ', -1)
```

One ounce is 0.0625 pounds.

Hence:

```
select *
from mytable 
where 
  cast( substring_index(col, ' ', 1) as decimal(10,2) ) *
  case when SUBSTRING_INDEX(col, ' ', -1) in ('ounce', 'ounces') then 0.0625 
       when SUBSTRING_INDEX(col, ' ', -1) in ('pound', 'pounds') then 1
       else null
  end <= 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

its very bad idea to store numeric data as strings, anyway you can try to convert it back, like this:

```
select *
from (
select title,
(case
when title like '%ounce%' then title/16.0
when title like '%pound%' then title*1.0
else null
end) as weightinpound
from (
select '0.8 ounces' as title union all
select '1.8 ounces' union all
select '1 ounce' union all
select '2 ounces' union all
select '15 ounces' union all
select '15.6 ounces' union all
select '1 pound' union all
select '9.9 pounds' union all
select '15 pounds' union all
select '100.1 pounds'
) as q
) as q2
where weightinpound <= 10.0
```

here is sample fiddle http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/56696

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a regexp, here is a working one that matches any float/integer values larger than 10 so that you can use `NOT REGEXP`:

```
where title NOT REGEXP '(^|[^[:alnum:].])(10([.]0*[1-9])|([0-9]{3}|[2-9][0-9]|1[1-9])([.][0-9]*)?)[[:space:]]*pound'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cN4jD1/1) and the [SQL fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/56703).

The pattern details:

- `(^|[^[:alnum:].])` - either start of string or a non-alphanumeric and not a dot
- `(10([.]0*[1-9])` - `10` followed with a decimal separator, 0+ zeros and a non-zero digit
  `|([0-9]{3}` - or any 3 digits
  `|[2-9][0-9]` - or 20 till 99 integer number
  `|1[1-9])` - or `11-19` integer number
- `([.][0-9]*)?)` - one or zero (optional) decimal part
- `[[:space:]]*pound` - 0+ whitespaces followed with the word "pound".

Comment: I notice you used the singular "pound" instead of the plural "pounds." Does it matter?

Comment: It does not, but if you need it to be `pounds`, add `s[[:>:]]`: `'(^|[^[:alnum:].])(10([.]0*[1-9])|([0-9]{3}|[2-9][0-9]|1[1-9])([.][0-9]*)?)[[:space:]]*pounds[[:>:]]'`